# How can I get the overall total count of the SchoolDetail.Name?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT     
    Districts.DistrictDescription,Count(SchoolDetail.Name) As Responded, 
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.WaterAssetCondition = 'Improved' Then 1 Else 0 End) as H2Improved,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.WaterAssetCondition = 'Unimproved' Then 1 Else 0 End) as H2NotImproved,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.WaterTypeFunc = 'Functional' Then 1 Else 0 End) as H2Func,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.WaterTypeFunc = 'Not Functional' Then 1 Else 0 End) as H2NotFunc,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.ToiletsImproved = 'Improved' Then 1 Else 0 End) as ToiletsImproved,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.ToiletsImproved = 'Unimproved' Then 1 Else 0 End) as ToiletsUnimproved,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.ToiletsFunc = 'Functional' Then 1 Else 0 End) as ToiletsFunc,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.ToiletsFunc = 'Not Functional' Then 1 Else 0 End) as ToiletsNotFunc,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.FuncToiletsAccessible = 'Yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) as Accessible,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.FuncToiletsAccessible = 'No' Then 1 Else 0 End) as NotAccessible,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.StudentToiltesSexSeparated = 'Yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) as SexSep,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.StudentToiltesSexSeparated = 'No' Then 1 Else 0 End) as NoSexSep,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.HandWashFacWithWater = 'Yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) as HandWashWater,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.HandWashFacWithWater = 'No' Then 1 Else 0 End) as NoHandWashWater,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.HandWashFacWithWaterSoap = 'Yes' Then 1 Else 0 End) as HandWashWaterSoap,
    Sum(Case When School_WASH.HandWashFacWithWaterSoap = 'No' Then 1 Else 0 End) as NoHandWashWaterSoap
FROM
    Districts 
INNER JOIN
    SchoolDetail ON Districts.ID = SchoolDetail.DistrictID 
INNER JOIN
    School_WASH ON SchoolDetail.Code = School_WASH.SchoolCode
WHERE
    School_WASH.SchoolYear = '2016'
GROUP BY
    Districts.DistrictDescription
```

Comment: can you please detail what you need.. if you say count you just use count from specific table but your script  had joins so a bit absurd

Comment: I need the overall count of SchoolDetail.Name and not the only count of the executed query - which is the count in the above query

Comment: I need the overall cout outside that query

Comment: Isn't that what `Count(SchoolDetail.Name) As Responded` does? No? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i,ve got the count from my query which is 15.....i want the total count from the database which is 1034...so that i can percentage each Districts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand what you are looking for, you just need to run your count as a subquery

replace this:

```
Count(SchoolDetail.Name) As Responded
```

by

```
(select count(Name) from SchoolDetail)  As Responded
```